# Draw rounded linear gradient (or extended radial gradient) with CoreGraphics

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-graphics, gradient

I want to do some custom drawing with CoreGraphics. I need a linear gradient on my view, but the thing is that this view is a rounded rectangle so I want my gradient to be also rounded at angles. You can see what I want to achieve on the image below:
[image: Example: Rounded rectangle with rounded linear gradient.]

So is this possible to implement in CoreGraphics or some other programmatic and easy way?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an API for that, but you can get the same effect if you first draw a radial gradient, say, in an `(N+1)x(N+1)` size bitmap context, then convert the image from the context to a resizable image with left and right caps set to `N`.

Pseudocode:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(N+1,N+1), NO, 0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// <draw the gradient into 'context'>

UIImage* gradientBase = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImage* gradientImage = [gradientBase resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,N,0,N)];
```

In case you want the image to scale vertically as well, you just have to set the caps to `UIEdgeInsetsMake(N,N,N,N)`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. And if we convert radial gradient to image and stretch it, then the sides of gradient will be also stretched (will become oval instead of circle), am I right?

Comment: If you do it with the resizableImage API then it won't get distorted because only the pixels outside the cap are resized/tiled.

Comment: I've tried to implement this, and it looks that it should work great, but I have one problem. I get the resizable image of my radial gradient with insets defined and when I draw it in some point with `[gradientImage drawAtPoint: point]` it draws my radial gradient. But when I want to draw it in my rect with `[gradientImage drawInRect:myRect]` method, it isn't stretched, but is drawn tiled several times instead. But When I don't apply `resizableImageWithCapInsets` then it is stretched. Is it normal behavior? I want to draw a stretched image, not tiled.

Comment: Well that's the expected behaviour. If you want the middle part (the one outside the cap) to be stretched, set the caps as above to get a 1 pixel wide non-capped region for which tiling is equivalent to stretching. Anything wider than that will inevitably get tiled.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add more sample code for this technique, as some things weren't obvious for. Maybe it will be useful for somebody:

So, let's say, we have our custom view class and in it's `drawRect:` method we put this:

```
// Defining the rect in which to draw
CGRect drawRect=self.bounds;
Float32 gradientSize=drawRect.size.height;   // The size of original radial gradient
CGPoint center=CGPointMake(0.5f*gradientSize,0.5f*gradientSize);  // Center of gradient

// Creating the gradient
Float32 colors[4]={0.f,1.f,1.f,0.2f};  // From opaque white to transparent black
CGGradientRef gradient=CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(), colors, nil, 2);

// Starting image and drawing gradient into it
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(gradientSize, gradientSize), NO, 1.f);
CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawRadialGradient(context, gradient, center, 0.f, center, center.x, 0);  // Drawing gradient
UIImage* gradientImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();  // Retrieving image from context
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();  // Ending process
gradientImage=[gradientImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.f, center.x-1.f, 0.f, center.x-1.f)];  // Leaving 2 pixels wide area in center which will be tiled to fill whole area

// Drawing image into view frame
[gradientImage drawInRect:drawRect];
```

That's all. Also if you're not going to ever change the gradient while app is running, you would want to put everything except last line in `awakeFromNib` method and then in `drawRect:` just draw the gradientImage into view's frame. Also don't forget to retain the `gradientImage` in this case.